What is libstdc++ compatibility principle?
I was told that libstdc++.so is often carried along with a built app. The reason is https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html (I was told).
I grep strings output for gcc 7.3 library:
libstdc++.so.6.0.24 | grep CXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.9
CXXABI_1.3.10
CXXABI_1.3.11

As far as I understand, this means that the version of this library is GLIBCXX_3.4.24/CXXABI_1.3.11. But the result of compilation will run on the machines having libstdc++ with all the lesser GLIBCXX/CXXABI listed above.
However, the GCC 5.1 ABI change happened for GCC 5.1.0: GLIBCXX_3.4.21, CXXABI_1.3.9 (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html). So I expected the compatibility list above would not contain versions below GLIBCXX_3.4.21, CXXABI_1.3.9. But it does contain.

What is wrong with my understanding about the compatability list?
All the more, why would developers need to carry libstdc++.so along with their app if the compatibility list is so long? Maybe there is another reason?
What are the difference between GLIBCXX and CXXABI symbols? Cannot find the info.
Are GLIBCXX and CXXABI about ABI, API or both?


personally, i use C++23 on operating systems from 2018 (used to be 2008 but decided to drop support), i cannot trust that the system's libstdc++ can run my application, so you end up having to pack libstdc++ and libgcc with your application.

if your application is deployed through the system's package manager then you don't need to ship libstdc++ because the system should have the same one that was used to build your application, but if you are deploying just your application into a platform whose default compiler cannot be used to build your executable then you need to pack libstdc++. packing libgcc has its downsides, like you cannot catch exceptions out of system libraries, but all of those have a C API anyway and don't throw exceptions, so you can also ship it if you want.

Your question is confusing and difficult to answer. It is not clear what makes you even worry about compatibility?
One thing is clear though: your understanding of the "compatibility list" is wrong. You just grepped for strings through a binary and accidentally happened to find some symbol matches. This is not how compatibility info is published. If you want to know about library versions, look at the page in the GCC manual you linked. Try to understand this page.
If you are facing an actual, concrete compatibility problem, try to post that as a new question
